# ubuntu downgrade from lucid to karmic

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10, ubuntu-10.04, downgrade

I was foolish to upgrade my computer to lucid, and i got into a lot of errors, it will not boot proper the display.

This is why i want to downgrade back to Karmic.

Do you know how can you do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

^agreed.
However, I was able to re-install without losing essential data. I have explained it here:
http://www.khattam.info/2010/03/15/howto-downgrading-from-ubuntu-10-04-lucid-lynx-to-9-10-karmic-koala/

Answer (score 0):

Restore from the backup you made before upgrading?  You made a backup right?

Seriously, you probably need to backup your data/configuration format and reinstall.  There is no supported way on a Debian/Ubuntu based system to downgrade.